Invalid FilterExpression: Attribute name is a reserved keyword; reserved keyword: type
I have a DynamoDB table with some string datatype attributes (sample below). I use the AWS CLI to download this data in my local Mac.
I want to scan/query the DynamoDB table and download all the records that match a certain condition. As I want to pull all the records that have address type = Home, I assume that I have to use scan, but when I issue this command I get this error:
Invalid FilterExpression : Attribute name is a reserved keyword; reserved keyword: type. 

aws dynamodb scan--table-name my_table \
--filter-expression "type = :address_type" \ 
--expression-attribute-values '{":address_type: {"S": "Home"}}'


id     |     name       |     address      |       type 
john   |     doe        |    123 pearl st  |       Home 
....

I've tried without the filter expression and the command works.


Invalid FilterExpression : Attribute name is a reserved keyword; reserved keyword: type.

Unforunately, you've used a reserved word, type, as an attribute name.  But don't worry, all is not lost.  It's a little more cumbersome to handle reserved attribute names, but not too bad.
Just like the value :address_type in the filter expression is a placeholder for an attribute value defined in --expression-attribute-values, #type can be a placeholder for an attribute name defined in --expression-attribute-names.

aws dynamodb scan --table-name my_table \
--filter-expression "#type = :address_type" \ 
--expression-attribute-values '{":address_type: {"S": "Home"}}' \
--expression-attribute-names '{"#type": "type"}'

